# Webpack Module build failed: SyntaxError on certain ts syntax

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack

I'm building a small app with webpack, angularjs and typescript. My project is building and running, until I use certain es6 features, then it breaks. I've checked a few different issues and tweaked my files and I haven't had any success. It won't allow me to define class properties, "declare var foo;", or a few other bizarre corner cases. sass is building fine.

webpack.config.ts

```
    let path = require('path');
    module.exports = {
      cache: true,
      entry: {
        main: './client/app/app.module.ts'
      },
      output: {
        path: __dirname + '/../client/dist/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js'
      },
      module: {
        loaders: [{
          test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loaders: ['ts-loader']
        },
        {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        }]
      },
      plugins: [
      ],
      devtool: "source-map",
      resolve: {
        // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx']
      },
    };
```

tsconfig.json

```
            {
                "compilerOptions": {
                    "target": "es5",
                    "module": "commonjs",
                    "sourceMap": false,
                    "noImplicitAny": false,
                    "watch": true
                }
            }
```

layout.controller.ts

```
    import * as angular from 'angular';

    class LayoutController{
      private test:number;
      constructor() {

      }
    }

    LayoutController.$inject = [
    ];

    export default LayoutController;
```

Error

```
    [0] ERROR in ./client/app/layout/layout.controller.ts
    [0] Module build failed: SyntaxError:C:/Users/user/Documents/Projects/Portfolio/client/app/layout/layout.controller.ts: Unexpected token (4:10)
    [0]
    [0]   2 |
    [0]   3 | class LayoutController{
    [0] > 4 |   private test:number;
    [0]     |           ^
    [0]   5 |   constructor() {
    [0]   6 |
    [0]   7 |   }
    [0]
    [0]  @ ./client/app/layout/layout.module.ts 11:14-44
    [0]  @ ./client/app/app.module.ts
```

Comment: Pasting this code in my IDE there are no syntax errors when linting with `"typescript": "2.0.10"`. Which version do you use and are you sure TypeScript is transpiling? Because it sounds like it is not, because normal JS does not know "private", but TypeScript does

Comment: Indeed it looks like a webpack issue, it looks ok but perhaps wrong webpack version?